# Why does this code does not work as function?

Tags: python, function

I'm new to python and this should be a simple function practice exercise.

I wrote this function that should put in upper case every character of a string in which the index is even, but it didn`t work.

When I wrote a very similar (but not as function), it worked. Why?

##### Code_1:

```
h = 'abcdefg'
f = ''

for stuff in h:
    if h.index(stuff) % 2 == 0:
        f = f + stuff.upper()
    else:
        f = f + stuff.lower()
        
print(f)
```

`Output: AbCdEfG`

##### Code_2:

```
h = 'abcdefg'

def func_test(*a):
    
    f = ''
    
    for stuff in a:
        if a.index(stuff) % 2 == 0:
            f = f + stuff.upper()
        else:
            f = f + stuff.lower()
    return f

func_test(h)
```

`Output: 'ABCDEFG'`

Comment: In your own words, where you have written `def func_test(*a):`, what do you intend as the purpose of the `*`?

Answer (score 5):

I think it might be a mistake but, at the moment you are passing in `args`.

```
def func(*args)
```

notice the asterisk before the argument. Doing this in your program will give us

```
('abcdefg',)
```

So, take this away and you can easily iterate through the string.

```
h = 'abcdefg'

def func_test(a):
    f = ''
    
    for stuff in a:
        if a.index(stuff) % 2 == 0:
            f = f + stuff.upper()
        else:
            f = f + stuff.lower()
    return f

print(func_test(h))
```

**tradition** create online

```
x = lambda a: ''.join([let.upper() if count % 2 == 0 else let for count,let in enumerate(a)])
print(x('abcdefg'))
```

output

```
AbCdEfG
```

Comment: It was exactly that, I should have reviewed it with more attention. Thank you very much!